# SwiftUI NavigationLink behaviour is different when selection is set directly, rather than from viewModel

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I've been working with SwiftUI and ran into unexpected behavior.

I have View A and View B and View C. View C has EnviromentObject that changes AppState from View A

View B has ViewModel with selection

If I call function from ViewModel to change the selection then
View C is shown for a few seconds and then it automatically pops back to View B

If I change selection directly from View B (not from ViewModel), everything works as expected.
Also, if I comment out onDissapear, it also works. But, I need to change environmentObject when screen dissapeared
Here is View B and ViewModel

```
import SwiftUI

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var shouldHideUserInfo = false
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject
    var appState: AppState
    
    @State
    var selection: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if !appState.shouldHideUserInfo {
                    Text("USER INFO")
                }
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ViewA(),
                    tag: 1,
                    selection: $selection,
                    label: { EmptyView()})
                
                Button("MOVE TO VIEW A") {
                    selection = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


class ViewAModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var selection: Int? = nil
    
    func navigate() {
        selection = 2 //<- this doesnt
    }
}

struct ViewA: View {
    
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel: ViewAModel
    
    init() {
        viewModel = ViewAModel()
    }

    @State
    var selection: Int? = nil //<- this works
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            Text("VIEW A")
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ViewB(),
                tag: 2,
                selection: $viewModel.selection,
                label: { EmptyView()})
            
            Button("MOVE TO VIEW B") {
                //selection = 2 <-- this works
                viewModel.navigate() //<- this doesnt
            }
           
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject
    var appState: AppState

    @State
    var selection: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            Text("VIEW B")
           
        }
        .onAppear {
            appState.shouldHideUserInfo = true
        }
    }
}
```

Factory pattern didn't solve the issue:

```
    static func makeViewA(param: Int?) -> some View {
        let viewModel = ViewAModel(param: param)
        return ViewA(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works same with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Which environment do you use?

Comment: @Asperi my environment is the same. One moment I have created a minimum git repo where this issue is reproducible. https://github.com/martynasNarijauskas/swiftui

Comment: + I updated current code, so it will be enough just copying it and setting env object from scene delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see... it is a bit different than in post. The issue is because view model is recreated (this is long observed behavior of `NavigationView`) and thus binding lost.

The quick fix is

```
struct ViewA: View {
    
    @StateObject
    var viewModel: ViewAModel = ViewAModel()
    
    init() {
//        viewModel = ViewAModel()
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

alternate is to keep ownership of view model outside of `ViewA`.

**Update: SwiftUI 1.0 compatible** - here is variant that works everywhere. The reason of the issue is in `AppState`. The code in `ViewB` updates `appState`

```
.onAppear {
    appState.shouldHideUserInfo = true
}
```

that causes rebuild of `ContentView` body, which recreates `ViewA`, which recreates `NavigationLink`, which drops previous link and `ViewB` got closed.

To prevent this we need to avoid rebuild `ViewA`. This can be done by making `ViewA` is-a `Equatable`, so SwiftUI check if `ViewA` needs to be recreated and we will answer NO.

Here is how it goes:

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: ViewA().equatable(),    // << here !!
    tag: 1,
    selection: $selection,
    label: { EmptyView()})
```

and

```
struct ViewA: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ViewA, rhs: ViewA) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    // .. other code
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific how can I keep the ownership of ViewModel outside of ViewA? I tried to create static func with factory pattern to create ViewA with already injected ViewModel, however it didn't solve the issue. I update my question with the code